# Como salvar no banco MySQL o insert Radio Button com BootStrap

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário de cadastro porém, precisei incluir um campo (Radio Button) no meu projeto. No entando, não estou conseguindo salvar o insert do Radio Button no meu banco MySQL.

O código abaixo está no padrão bootstrap , mas a variável **name** ao qual estava utilizando para definir os campos que seriam salvos nomeu banco, já está sendo utilizado pelo formato flexRadioDefault. Dessa forma, não consigo utilizá-la para realizar o inserto no banco, como foi feito nos demais campos do formulário.

Exemplo:

```html
<!-- FORMULÁRIO -->

<div class="col-sm">
  <label for="cep">Cep</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CEP" name="cep">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3">

  <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu Cargo" name="cargo">

</div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault">
    <label for="flexRadioDefault1">Homem</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault">
    <label for="flexCheckDefault2">Mulher</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```php
// INSERT BANCO

include "conexao.php";

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `formulario`(`nome`, `telefone`, `email1`, `email2`, `endereco`, `bairro`, `estado`, `cep`, `cargo`, `sexo`,) VALUES
('$nome','$telefone','$email1','$email2','$endereco','$bairro','$estado','$cep','$cargo','$sexo')";
```

Comment: Oi Caio. Adicione o trecho de código PHP onde vc tenta salvar o conteúdo desse formulário em seu banco de dados.

Comment: Tentei colocar  código debaixo da mesma forma, mas não deu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se baseando do exemplo do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#radios) você não precisa usar o mesmo `name` e `id` que eles usaram, apenas a mesma classe `form-check-input` e `form-check-input` que é onde estão as estilizações. O resto você adapta para o seu caso. Que depois de olhar seu código PHP, acredito que seja algo mais ou menos assim:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino" id="radio-sexo-masculino">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-sexo-masculino">
    Masculino
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Feminino" id="radio-sexo-feminino">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-sexo-feminino">
    Feminino
  </label>
</div>
```

dessa forma o conteudo deve estar dentro de `$_POST['sexo']`.

Sugiro usar Masculino e Feminino para opções de sexo, ao invés de Homem e Mulher [fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferen%C3%A7a_entre_sexo_e_g%C3%AAnero#Sexo).

E também pesquisar um pouco sobre [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php), pois parece que seu sistema está aberto a isso, e vc tem que tratar esses valores antes de fazer sua query

Comment: O problema quando eu altero a variável name= "flexRadioDefault" para name = "sexo", o RadioButton já fica marcado.

Comment: Estranho. o que faz o radio ficar marcado no exemplo acima é o atributo `checked` retirando ele, ambos estarão desmarcados por padrão

Comment: Na verdade ele até fica desmarcado. Mas quando marco um e depois o outro, ele não alterna a marcação, marcando os dois de uma vez.

Comment: Estava faltando o atributo `value` acima. agr o `$_POST['sexo']` deve vir vazio ou 'Masculino' ou 'Feminino'. Tente copiar o trecho para o seu código e veja se os dois campos ainda ficam marcados.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Nem sei como te agradecer. Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: Por nada @CaioFilipe . Considere aceitar a resposta como resolução da sua pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o seu problema é porque você precisa colocar um atributo value com o valor que você quer inserir do seu input, exemplo:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="M" name="flexRadioDefault">

<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="F" name="flexRadioDefault">
```

No php:

```
$gender = $_POST['flexRadioDefault'];
```